# Groovy to Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, groovy

I wanna convert the `groovy` task file to `kotlin dsl` file.
how this line written in `groovy` should look like in `kotlin dsl`?

```
task testz(type: JacocoReport) {
    additionalSourceDirs.setFrom files(subprojects.sourceSets.main.allSource.srcDirs)
}
```

I tried something like that

```
tasks.register<JacocoReport>("testz") {
    additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(subprojects{sourceSets()}))
}
```

but I do not know how to get `main.allSource.srcDirs`. I am not sure if I the code I have written is good at all

methods like `getByName` or `val main by getting` don't work

code below does not work too

```
 additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(subprojects {
     project.the<SourceSetContainer>().getByName("main").allSource.srcDirs
 }))
```

it shows me the error like this: `Extension of type 'SourceSetContainer' does not exist. Currently registered extension types: [ExtraPropertiesExtension]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
tasks.register<JacocoReport>("testz") {
    additionalSourceDirs.setFrom(files(subprojects { sourceSets["main"].allSource.srcDirs }))
}
```

Comment: already tried it, it shows me the error `Function invocation sourceSets(...) expected`